# Android and Arduino both receiving strange values via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, communication

I am using BluetoothChat code on the Android side to send an ON/OFF signal (I am sending 110, 119 or other cases as defined below) to the Arduino UNO using the chat box, but when I display the received value, it shows strange values in the Arduino Serial monitor, that is, 255, 254, 250 or 245 and replies with strange values on the Android side too.

but suprisingly only single condition among 110, 119, etc gets true when i send these commands from android and no other instruction/LED gets properly executed/turned ON/off.

Can any one help me figure out the problem? Below is my arduino code.

```
int data; 
String message; 

void setup () 
{ 
Serial.begin (57600); 

pinMode (6, OUTPUT); 
pinMode (7, OUTPUT); 
pinMode (8, OUTPUT); 
pinMode (9, OUTPUT); 
pinMode (10, OUTPUT); 

digitalWrite(6, LOW); // off LED 1 at pin6 
digitalWrite(7, LOW); // off LED 2 at pin7 
digitalWrite(8, LOW); // off LED 3 at pin8 
digitalWrite(9, LOW); // off LED 4 at pin9 
digitalWrite(10, LOW); // off LED 5 at pin10 
}

void loop () { 
int i=0; 
if (Serial.available()>0) 
{ 
int data= Serial.read(); 

Serial.println (" Received data: "); 
Serial.println (data); 

if (data==110) //q 
{ 
digitalWrite(6, HIGH); // turn on LED 1 at pin6 
message = "LED 1 On"; 
Serial.println (message); 

} 
if (data==102) // a 
{ 
digitalWrite(6, LOW); // off LED 1 at pin6 
message = "LED 1 Off"; 
Serial.println (message); 
} 

if (data==96) //c 
{ 
digitalWrite(7, HIGH); //on LED 2 
message = "LED 2 On"; 
Serial.println (message); 
} 

if (data==115) //d 
{ 
digitalWrite(7, LOW); // off LED 2 
message = "LED 2 Off"; 
Serial.println (message); 
} 

if (data==111) //e 
{ 
digitalWrite(8, HIGH); //on LED 3 
message = "LED 3 On"; 
Serial.println (message); 
} 

if (data==97)// f 
{ 
digitalWrite(8, LOW); //sets the LED 3 
message = "LED 3 Off"; 
Serial.println (message); 
} 

if (data==107) //g 
{ 
digitalWrite(9, HIGH); //turn on LED 4 
message = "LED 4 On"; 
Serial.println (message); 
} 

if (data==120)//h 
{ 
digitalWrite(9, LOW); //sets the LED 4 
message = "LED 4 Off"; 
Serial.println (message); 
} 


if (data==99) //i 
{ 
digitalWrite(10, HIGH); //sets the LED 5 
message = "L5 high"; 
Serial.println (message); 
} 

if (data==104) //j 
{ 
digitalWrite(10, LOW); //sets the LED 5 
message = "LED 5 Off"; 
Serial.println (message); 
} 

if (data==112) //y 
{ 
digitalWrite(6, HIGH); // turn on ALL LEDs 
digitalWrite(7, HIGH); 
digitalWrite(8, HIGH); 
digitalWrite(9, HIGH); 
digitalWrite(10, HIGH); 
message = "ALL LEDs ON"; 
Serial.println (message); 
} 


if (data==122)//z 
{ 
digitalWrite(6, LOW); //Turn off all LEDs 
digitalWrite(7, LOW); 
digitalWrite(8, LOW); 
digitalWrite(9, LOW); 
digitalWrite(10, LOW); 
Serial.println ("ALL LEDs OFF"); 
} 

else 
{ 
digitalWrite(13, HIGH); //sets the LED 5 
delay(3000); //3sec 
digitalWrite(13, LOW); 
delay(3000); 
Serial.println (" else case executed "); 

} ////end of else 

}
data=0;
}
```

Comment: I'm a total newbie on Arduino but if Serial.read() is reading from a bluetooth device then your Serial.println() calls are writing to that same bluetooth device, not to the Arduino serial monitor.

Comment: No i receive some some randomn values on serial monitor too like 255, 240. the values i receive my mobile are some what like ??/??? ??? ??

Answer (score 1):

Try **char data = Serial.read();**

And show Java code for Android.

See 100% work code for [Bluetooth Arduino&Android](http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino5.php)

Comment: Sir Анатолий Колтыков , i have tried char too. Well thanks let me work on the link too.. :-)

Comment: Dear Sir Анатолий Колтыков; the code provided on the link is for Android version 4.1 but i have 2.2. I am little new to android. Can you please tell me what changes will be required to make sure the Android application is working fine?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Arduino Uno, then you can't use the serial monitor to print values, if you are already using serial to communicate to Bluetooth, since it has only one serial port.

You have to use the Software serial library or use Arduino Mega, which has 4 serial ports.

Comment: thanks. sir @sudar I am using UNO. i tried some other code now, it is different, i get proper reply from arduino to mobile but corresponding LED condition does not executes properly i.e. When i send any letter or integer digit through BluetoothChat app. from my phone to arduino. it prints 255 or 254 on serial monitor. please can you guide me below is my arduino code

Comment: Arduino Code snapsots on https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.537304616296698.140354.100000514942282&type=3